# Salesforce JWT Login Returns Invalid Client Credentials

Tags: laravel, jwt, salesforce

All of the sudden i'm getting this error, can anyone shed some light on what is going on? Any help would be much appreciated.

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
> Client error: `POST https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"invalid client credentials"}

I've been using this for months now and has been working fine. Did Salesforce's JWT login change? I've checked the Digital Certificate and it hasn't expired yet.

I'm following this article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5 and it says that they don't issue a refresh token so i'm not sure why i'd be getting this error.

Here's my code:

```
function create_assertion()
{
    $signer = new \Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256();
    $keychain = new \Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Keychain();
    $builder = new \Lcobucci\JWT\Builder();
    $token = $builder->setIssuer(env('CONSUMER_KEY'))
        ->setAudience(env('LOGIN_URL'))
        ->setExpiration(strval(time() + (5 * 60)))
        ->setSubject(env('USERNAME'))
        ->sign($signer, $keychain->getPrivateKey(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . env("SALESFORCE_PK_FILE"))))->getToken();
    return $token->__toString();
}

function create_jwt($third_party_name)
{
    try {
        $client = new GuzClient(['base_uri' => env('LOGIN_URL')]);
        $r = json_decode($client->post("/services/oauth2/token", [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
                'assertion' => create_assertion()
            ]
        ])->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        return saveTheAccessToken($r, $third_party_name);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        sendEmail('my@email.com', 'Salesforce API Error', $exception->getMessage());
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: No changes still not working. I've done the following without success too

```
function base64url_encode($data)
{
    return str_replace('/', '_', str_replace('+', '-', base64_encode($data)));
}
function create_assertion()
{
    $jsonHeader = json_encode(["alg" => "RS256"]);
    $header = base64url_encode($jsonHeader);

    $expiration = strval(time() + (5 * 60));

    $claimSet = [
        "iss" => env('CONSUMER_KEY'),
        "sub" => env('USERNAME'),
        "aud" => env('LOGIN_URL'),
        "exp" => $expiration
    ];
    $jsonClaimSet = json_encode($claimSet);
    $payload = base64url_encode($jsonClaimSet);
    $encoded_JWT = $header . '.' . $payload;
    $private_key = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . env("SALESFORCE_PK_FILE"));

    $signature = "";
    $algo = "SHA256";
    openssl_sign($encoded_JWT, $signature, $private_key, $algo);
    $secret = base64url_encode($signature);
    return $header . '.' . $payload . '.' . $secret;
}
```

Could it be my private key or the cert I uploaded to SF? I haven't made any changes to either. The cert expires end of next month.

Comment: Is the connected app (where you'd see client id a.k.a. consumer key) OK? Any chance you've been using a connected app created in sandbox and admin eventually refreshed it, killing the app? Are you able to use same consumer key in human-driven login, for example paste it to https://openidconnect.herokuapp.com/ or if you're paranoid call https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5 from your Postman/SoapUI/curl/what have you...

Comment: Is the connected app (where you'd see client id a.k.a. consumer key) OK? Yes, it hasn't changed.

Any chance you've been using a connected app created in sandbox and admin eventually refreshed it, killing the app? No, because we've been using it in prod for months and have been getting the correct/prod data. (Myself and one other are the admin).